# How can i buy Sims 3 Mac platform?

Tags: macos, mac, software

as the title, already looking at EA store site at http://store.origin.com/store/eara/en_SG/DisplayProductDetailsPage/productID.105153500/pgm.64539100

But seems they only sale PC version only.
But when i go to IE site it says sale for mac too???
http://www.ea.com/the-sims-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The SIMS 3 for OS X](http://gametreemac.com/EA-Electronic-Arts/Buy-The-SIMS-3-Mac-Download) can be bought online through GameTree -- they handle OS X online game distribution for EA.

Comment: Thanks to my lovely wife. Her SIMS addiction is the reason I knew how to answer this.